# can't read first character of array in c

Tags: c, arrays, format-specifiers

I'm trying to read the characters of a character array by number in c. I've stripped the program down to isolate the problem. I know this is about my misunderstanding of how arrays and memory works and I am ready to be called clueless but I would like to know what I am misunderstanding here. Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buffer[] = "stuff";
    printf("buffer is %s\n", buffer);
    printf("first character of buffer is %s", (char)buffer[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("first character of buffer is %c\n", buffer[0]);`

Comment: Thanks BLUEPIXY if you make that an answer I'll credit you with it.

Comment: Thanks to everyone these were all great answers, and if I could I'd accept them all. To be fair I accepted the first one that was listed as an answer.

Comment: If you're not using `argc` and `argv`, it is better to use `int main(void)` for the definition of `main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write the correct format specifier. Now you used `%s` ...what happens? 
It looks for an string which is null terminated. But it doesn't find one. So it simply cant put anything in the output . That's it.
Use `%c` instead.

Comment: The problem is that it is passed a small integer and when it tries to interpret that small integer as the address of the start of a string, you invoke undefined behaviour.  It might crash because the address is not valid; it might go reading data from the address until it happens upon a null byte, but the content will be unrelated to the string in `buffer` except by (implausible) accident.

Comment: yea ..that happens. It tries to interpret it. As I said I will incorporate this answer when I get some time. Thanks for the answer and reply. @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 2):

In C there is a very big difference between a character and a string.
A character is simply a number in a range of 256 different options.
A string is not really a type of its own, it is merely an array of chars (which, in C, is simply evaluated as a pointer to the first character of the string).

Now, when you type buffer[0], this is evaluated to the value at the beginning of the string (first value in the array). Indeed, this is of char type (and therefore you do not need the (char) casting, because this will not do anything in the case of your code).

What you need is to tell printf() how to evaluate the input that you give it. %s is for a string (an array of chars). But note and remember that buffer[0] is not an array of chars, but rather *a* char.
So you actually want to use %c, instead of %s. This tells printf() to evaluate the parameter as a char type.
What your code currently does is take the value buffer[0] (which is just a number) and consider it as a pointer to a location in memory where a string is kept, and printf() tries to print this string. But this memory location is simply invalid. It is not a location you've accessed before.

In conclusion you want:

```
printf("first character of buffer is %c", (char)buffer[0]);
```

or even simpler:

```
printf("first character of buffer is %c", buffer[0]);
```

For other specifiers of the printf() function, look here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print only a single char use `%c` format.

```
printf("first character of buffer is %c\n", (char)buffer[0]);
```

Comment: Given that `buffer` is an array of `char`, what is the type of `buffer[0]`?  So what value does the cast provide?